# Why is it incorrect to say "Without a car, it takes a long time to get from a place to another."?

Tags: grammar, articles

This is the exact text from the Longman dictionary of common errors:

Incorrect: Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **a** place to another.
Correct: Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **one** place to another.
from one ... to another (NOT from a/an ... to another): 'The job involves traveling from one country to another.'

So, why can't we say from **a** place to another?

Comment: There is no intrinsic reason why you shouldn't be able to say it, and indeed you can. The only thing to keep in mind is that nobody else ever says that, so you will sound like a non-native speaker. (Which, again, depending on the circumstances, might very much be your whole goal.)

Answer (score 1):

> Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **a/one** place to another.

**A** place = one **general** example of a place taken from a **non-finite** number of places.

*[**The** place = that place of which we (speaker and listener) are both aware.]*

**One** place = one **specific**  example of place taken from a limited number of places: *One place where you will find apples is below an apple tree.*

**Another** is a pronoun with its referent as a previously mentioned substantive.

The statement also implies that it is normal to drive a car on a **specific** journey and so the places are **specific**: it is journeys like these that are referred to.

1 Without a car, it takes a long time to get from a place to another. = Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **any one of an infinite number of places** to another place from among  **an infinite number of other places**

2 Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **one** place to another. = Without a car, it takes a long time to get from **a specific place** to another **specific place**.

Comment: Thank you so much.